# inject ejb bean with mappedname in another bean without using name

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, jndi, lookup

I have a two ejb's in an EAR on glassfish, both implementing remote interfaces why they have both a mapped name assigned to them for client jndi lookup.

Now I want to inject one into the other. 
I successfully injected a Singleton Bean without any annotated name in my ejb's.
But this here is not working.

Is it necessary to do a JNDI lookup here, even when its local?

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ChildBean")
public class ChildBean implements ChildBeanRemote {}

@Stateless(mappedName = "ParentBean")
public class ParentBean implements ParentBeanRemote
{
    @EJB
    private ChildBean childBean;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ChildBean")
public class ChildBean implements ChildBeanRemote {}

@Stateless(mappedName = "ParentBean")
public class ParentBean implements ParentBeanRemote
{
    @EJB
    private ChildBeanRemote childBean; //You should use the interface and not the bean
}
```

Comment: thanks it works now, still don't get it why i must inject the interface and not the class itself if its on the same machine

Comment: This is because you want an EJB to be injected and not any regular POJO. EJBs are accessible only through their exposed methods through an interface because an EJB could be deployed on any remote server. The way youy have implemented wont work even if you had used a local interface because of it being an EJB and it is no different from calling one ejb to another - you always lookup the second ejb from your first ejb and then invoke a method on the second one. Hope this clarifies. Even if you were injecting a POJO through Spring or soem framework, it is always a good practice to use interfaces.

Comment: But why can a @Singleton bean without any interface be injected on the same jvm directly. This actually is not that straight forward.

Comment: Since ChildBean already implements ChildBeanRemote (which is annotated with @Remote) then in order to explicitly export no-interface view (in addition to already exported remote interface) add @LocalBean annotation to ChildBean. Then you can inject ChildBean local no-interface view into ParentBean.